# is FB's db (Oracle?) of "available username" in 'real-time' or gets updated dayly/wekly or never?

Tags: database, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Scenario:

there is FB user with Facebook (FB) ID and personal profile.
that FB ID also has one Page.

Now that ID wants to assign an available username "Myusername" to its Page (not assigning that available "Myusername" to ID itself).

Error occurred and available "MyUsername" got assigned to ID .

In order to correct that, and to release "MyUsername" to the availability status,
ID's username "MyUsername" is changed to "NewReplacingUseername" .

However, when then trying to assign "MyUsername" (expected to be now AGAIN availabe) to the ID's  Page,   FB returns  "Username not availabe".

However,

https://graph.facebook.com/MyUsername

returns

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: MyUsername",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

which should mean that "MyUsername" IS available !

Any help ?

========================
@OffBySome

thanks for pointing to that FAQ.

But that FAQ use terminology 
"securing" a username 
and 
"diffrent account".

But this is NOT "different" account.

Page belong to the same ID account to which username was initially (arroneously) given but later that username to ID itself was replaced with NewUserName in order to free original Username to be given to the Page of same account to which ID belongs to.

As for "securing" , it is not anymore "secured" as it was replaced with NewUsername.

I need tech confirmation:  Does FB store FOREVER any 'username' ever typed, even in error,
even if an account, who typed it in the first place, REPLACED it with something different,  i.e. it is not used anymore / it is abandon ?

And, once again, this is within SAME account !

Comment: thanks OffBySome for pointing to that FAQ. But that FAQ use terminology "securing" a username and "diffrent account".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot transfer a user name.  Once it has been assigned it cannot be re-assigned so that is why you are getting that error message.  This is documented on their [FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=211628848869527#Can-I-transfer-my-username-to-another-account?):

> **Can I transfer my username to another account?** 
>  Once you have secured a
>   username, it is not possible to transfer it to a different account on
>   Facebook. Also, when an account is removed from the site, its username
>   will be unavailable. Facebook does this for security reasons, namely
>   to prevent username squatting.

Comment: This is so annoying!  ...any chance to request support and have someone on FB freeing that username ?

Comment: I'm sending a request thru this form and cross my fingers, although I know changes are I will never get that username back https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=pages_bug